# Error Building A PhotoGallery

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

I have 8 MovieClips on my stage and I am trying to make a photo gallery using this script:

```
var photo :XML = new XML();
var imgURL :Array = new Array();
var imgCaptions :Array = new Array();
var thumbImg :Array = new Array();
var totImgs : Number = 0;
var imgAtual : Number = 1;
var xPos :Number = Stage.width;
var yPos :Number = Stage.height;
var mclThumb :MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
var listenerThumb :Object = new Object();

photo.ignoreWhite = true;

photo.onLoad = function(success) {
 if(success) {
  var photos :Array = new Array();

  photos = this.firstChild.childNodes;

  for(var i :Number = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
   imgURL.push(photos[i].attributes.images);
   thumbImg.push(photos[i].attributes.thumb);
   imgCaptions.push(photos[i].attributes.descricao);
  }

  totImgs = imgURL.length;
 }
}

photo.load("photos.xml");

buildThumb = function() {
 for(var i :Number = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  loadMovie(thumbImg[imgAtual],_root["img" + i]);
 }
}

buildThumb();
```

if I test it I will have an error like this:

Error opening URL "file:///C|/Documents%20and%20Settings/Eduardo%20Tavares/My%20Documents/Web%20Sites/site%20dj/images/undefined"

if I remove buildThumb?s function I get no error but It doesnt load anything.

here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<slideshow>
<photo images="foto1.jpg" thumb="thumb1.jpg" descricao="DJ Chambinho fazendo o Gas     Total" />
<photo images="foto2.jpg" thumb="thumb2.jpg" descricao="DJ Chambinho fazendo o Gas     Total" />
<photo images="foto3.jpg" thumb="thumb3.jpg" descricao="DJ Chambinho fazendo o Gas     Total" />
<photo images="foto4.jpg" thumb="thumb4.jpg" descricao="DJ Chambinho fazendo o Gas     Total" />
<photo images="foto5.jpg" thumb="thumb5.jpg" descricao="DJ Chambinho fazendo o Gas     Total" />
<photo images="foto6.jpg" thumb="thumb6.jpg" descricao="DJ Chambinho fazendo o Gas     Total" />
<photo images="foto7.jpg" thumb="thumb7.jpg" descricao="DJ Chambinho fazendo o Gas     Total" />
<photo images="foto8.jpg" thumb="thumb8.jpg" descricao="DJ Chambinho fazendo o Gas     Total" />
</slideshow>
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm loadmovie... try using loader in as3.0 instead of loadmovie, i would also suggest try loading an image first for testing in another fla for testing ... loaders script is below ... hoep this helps...

function loadClip(addrs:String):void
{
var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
 ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.Complete, loadComplete);
 var url:String = addrs;
 var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
 ldr.load(urlReq);
 addChild(ldr);
}

function loadComplete(evt:Event):void
{
    trace("movie loaded");
}